# What versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox are compatible on MacOS

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

Can anyone provide what versions are compatible please for vagrant/ virtual box on mac mojave 10.14.2.  I'm trying to learn these technologies from scratch.

I currently have **vagrant 1.7.1** and **virtualbox 6.0.0r127566**

```
> vagrant --version
> Vagrant 1.7.1
```

After a fresh install of the programs running this command returns the following error

```
> vagrant status
> No usable default provider could be found for your system.
  Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
  "providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
  environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

  The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, 
  which is available for free on all major platforms.

  If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
  is properly installed and configured. You can see more details 
  about why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
  `vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more 
  specific error message for that particular provider.
```

A previous message I received in the terminal suggested to downgrade to version 4 of VirtualBox but looking at the website the versions mentioned in the error message are not supported now.

[virtualbox 4.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_0)

[virtualbox 4.1](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_1)

[virtualbox 4.2](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2)

Thanks!

Comment: I would say either upgrade vagrant or perhaps try to run it as administrator and see what happens? Does " vagrant --version " work? (no quotes)

Comment: I've added the output from that command to the question details - how do I run it as administrator on a mac?

Comment: Try upgrading vagrant to the latest version (2.2.2), available from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html. The combination of vagrant 2.2.2 and virtualbox 6.0 works on my machine running mojave 10.14.2

Comment: In order to have admin privileges on a Mac follow the steps below https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

Comment: But I think I would listen to @mlidal  and update your vagrant

Comment: That's resolved it, do you want to add that as an answer so it can be marked as the solution?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading vagrant to the latest version (2.2.2), available from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html. The combination of vagrant 2.2.2 and virtualbox 6.0 works on my machine running mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Virtualbox 6.0.what?? :) I had 2.2.5 & 6.0.12 mounting fails. Tried 2.2.2 & 6.0.10 didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Even though upgrading should usually be the solution, if (like me) your running an older computer/OS then downgrading will be the only way to make it work.

In my case VirtualBox v5.1.38 and Vagrant v1.9.6 worked for me on an old Macbook running OSX 10.11.16 (El Capitan)

Note: I did try multiple configurations of Vagrant 2.x and VirtualBox 6.1/6.0.18, everything installed ok but all `vagrant` CLI commands simply gave no output when run, including no error being shown.

Running `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` will tell you which versions of VirtualBox your current Vagrant installation supports

Vagrant previous version downloads - https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/

VirtualBox previous version downloads - https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_0